# How to define an alias to a pointer to an integer?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, gnu

I am trying to run the following code, but I am getting the following error.

error: cannot declare pointer to 'int&'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *ptr = &x;

    int &(*y) = ptr;
    *y = 5;

    cout << *ptr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `int *&y = ptr;`, but it won't make a difference from `int *y = ptr;` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a new pointer to the same region of memory, use:

```
int *y = ptr;
```

This not so much an "alias" in that if you change `*ptr` or `*y`, both will change, but if you change the pointers themselves, the other will not be updated.

If you actually do want a reference to a pointer, use:

```
int *&y = ptr;
```

Comment: should we use brackets or not ( int *(&y) = ptr; )? If we don't use brackets, does * cancels out &?

Comment: @Moiz Sajid this is variable declaration (reads from right to left - reference to pointer to int), not dereferencing an address of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You declare references to pointers the same way you declare references to basic types.

Consider:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0; // int

    int& ir = i; // int reference (reference to int)

    int* ip = &i; // int pointer (pointer to int)

    int*& ipr = ip; // int pointer reference (reference to pointer to int)

    *ip = 5;

    cout << *ipr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int *ptr = &x;
```

pointer value has an address and a type of x.

when you typed code above, the value of ptr is an address of x, and ptr know the type of x.

```
int * (&y) = ptr;
```

the code above is declaring variable 'y' (type:int*, define:ptr's reference)

reference variables should be declared and defined simultaneously.

anyway, as a result, ptr and y are pointing same memory address.

you can easily think y is a nickname of ptr.

so you can access the variable 'x' by using y, instead of ptr.

Answer (score 1):

`v` - a variable name.

`&v` - a variable that will be a reference of something.

`*&v` - a variable that will be a reference of a pointer to something

`int *&v` - a variable that will be a reference of a pointer to `int`

Or for a more interesting example,

`(*&v)[5]` - a variable that will be a reference of a pointer to an array of 5 something

`int (*&v)[5]` - a variable that will be a reference of a pointer to an array of 5 `int`