# Why can this kind of declaration work in C++?

Tags: c++, declaration

Passing an `int` to an uninitialized pointer cannot work. But passing a reference to an uninitialized pointer *can* work.

What's the mechanism behind this?

```cpp
    int a = 1;
    int &r = a;
    cout << &a << " " << &r << endl; // 0x61ff10 0x61ff10

    // can work
    int *p1;
    *p1 = r;
    cout << p1 << endl; // 0x61ff60

    // cannot work
    int *p2;
    *p2 = a;
    return 0;
```

The code below is how I tested these strange concepts [page 400 of cpp primer plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYNFB.png).

```cpp
const free_throws & clone(free_throws & ft)
{
    free_throws * pt;
    *pt = ft; // copy info
    return *pt; // return reference to copy
}
```

P.S.: I tried changing the value of `a` and `cout << *p1` always outputs the correct value:

```cpp
    int a = 3;
    int &r = a;
    cout << &a << " " << &r << endl;
    // can work
    int *p1;
    *p1 = r;
    cout << p1 << endl;

    cout << *p1; // always the right value
```

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and this [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and perhaps [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), a draft C++ standard. But **C is different of C++**. Read also the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Provide some [mre] in your next question

Comment: What do you mean by 'can work' or 'cannot work', usage of both `p1` and `p2` is Undefined Behavior, anything can happen for apparently working as you expect it to, to crashing the app.

Comment: If you're asking about C++ then please don't add tags for other unrelated programming languages.

Comment: `*p1 = r` is wrong as you dereference an uninitialized pointer which leads to *undefined behavior*. It's the exact same case as for `p2`.

Comment: What **buggy** OS are you using? Dereferencing uninitialized pointer causes **segmentation fault**.

Comment: @AkibAzmain no it doesn't. It's undefined behavior. It can cause a seg fault, it can do nothing, in can print gibberish it can do anything

Comment: @bolov Yes, but most of the time uninitialized pointer points to memory which is not allocated for program, causing segmentation fault.

Comment: @AkibAzmain my point was: you cannot expect/rely on a segfalt. And not receiving a segfault doesn't make the OS "buggy".

Comment: @Kaldrr I saw this kind of usage on the book cpp primer plus 6ed, and i post the code on the book

Comment: the code from the book is wrong. `*pt = ft;` leads to Undefined Behavior as `pt` is uninitialized

Comment: @Some programmer dude   i think so, i'm reading cpp primer plus, and i saw this kind of usage on it. Then i wrote few lines of code test it. the fisrt case can pass and work.

Comment: @ Akib Azmain win10 and g++

Comment: @Miao_txy it doesn't work. It "appears" to work due to the nature of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @AkibAzmain no, UB is UB.  undefined behavior means that _anything_ may make it work  , cause strange effects or break in any way possible, OS, compiler, settings, order of compilation, presence of your boss. "Program is working" is a kind of possible UB. Realistically probability of segfault  on Linux is very rare if you dereference an uninitialized pointer which isn't a nullptr. On WIndows there is o such thing as segfault but you likely would hit memory protection mechanism either in runtime or in kernel, but you avoid it if pinter lands into allowed memory range.

Answer (score 4):

This Code from C++ Primer Plus (You shoudln't confuse "C++ Primer" a recommended book with "C++ Primer Plus") is not valid:

```
const free_throws & clone(free_throws & ft)
{
    free_throws * pt;
    *pt = ft; // copy info
    return *pt; // return reference to copy
}
```

The text in the book above the shown code says:

> A second method is to use `new` to create new storage. You’ve already seen examples in
> which `new` creates space for a string and the function returns a pointer to that space.
> Here’s how you could do something similar with a reference

So the code meant to look like that (in an early revision of the book the `new` was there):

```
const free_throws & clone(free_throws & ft)
{
    free_throws * pt = new free_throws();
    *pt = ft; // copy info
    return *pt; // return reference to copy
}
```

If `new` is missing then it is undefined behavior.

After the code the book also mentions that:

> This makes jolly a reference to the new structure. There is a problem with this
> approach: You should use `delete` to free memory allocated by `new` when the memory is no longer needed.

So even with the `new` it is a really bad code style.

> i tried to change the value of a and `cout << *p1` can always output the correct value

`int *p1; *p1 = r;` is undefined behavior, the compiler could make wrong assumptions about the code due to that, resulting in the compiler or optimizer create an unexpected/unpredictable machine code.

But what will most likely happen in practice for the shown code is: You don't initialize `int *p1;` so `p1` holds an undetermined value, this means it points to an arbitrary location in memory. If you are lucky it points to a valid memory address of currently not used memory. With `*p1 = r;` you write to the memory at that memory address, if you are lucky nothing important is at that address so nothing bad happens, but you still write at a "random" position in memory. So you might get the correct result, but your code is still not valid.

But that's just one possible outcome that could happen.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help, this usage corresponds to the book

Comment: Isn't returning `const free_throws &` for a memory allocated with `new` a memory leak? You should return `const free_throws *`. Also, `clone` should accept `const free_throws & ft`

Comment: @Quarra yes it does. Which is also mentioned in the book after the code.

Comment: @Quarra I fully agree that the function is bad, I just refer to the book and how they meant that the function should look like. My corrected version is what the book wanted to show and is valid and will work. And you could also delete the allocated memory after the `clone`. But yes it is a horrible piece of code, and a book should make that more clear.

Comment: The problem is that the code is sooooo bad it's hard to actually release this memory in a correct way - a reference is returned, not a pointer, so technically you can't really do anything with the underlying memory.

Comment: @Quarra yes absolutely, it is a real bummer, that this book is called "C++ Primer Plus" which makes it really easy to confuse it with "C++ Primer" which is a really good book.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1;
int &r = a;
cout << &a << " " << &r << endl;
```

This is **ok** as every variable is initialized.

---

```
int *p1;
*p1 = r;
cout << p1 << endl;
```

This is incorrect because `p1` is uninitialized. Accessing it (i.e. `*p1` in your example) causes the program to have **Undefined Behavior**. Undefined behavior means anything can happen: the program can segfault, it can appear to work, it can print gibberish, really anything.

---

```
int *p2;
*p2 = a;
```

Same as previous. Access of uninitialized variable resulting in Undefined Behavior.

---

```
free_throws * pt;
*pt = ft;
```

Same as previous. Access of uninitialized variable resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: but the program can always print the right value whatever value i put in the var a

Comment: @Miao_txy that's unfortunate because it hides the problem. As I've said, that's the nature of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: thanks, i also find it a little bit strange, so i ask this stupid question.

Comment: @Miao_txy it's not a stupid question. The book is wrong and printing yourself the program gave you contradictory results.

Answer (score 0):

It is an **undefined behavior** in both cases, as `*p1` and `*p2` are uninitialized.

Check the instructions generated:

`int a = 1;` Variable `a` is stored and initialized in `rbp-28`:

```
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], 1
```

`int &r = a;` Then, alias `r` is stored in `rbp-8`, which is initialized reading `&a` using `lea` instruction:

```
    lea     rax, [rbp-28]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
```

`int *p1; *p1 = r;` Pointer `*p1` is stored in `rbp-16`. The last `mov` assigns `*p1 = a` without initializing `p1` to any value:

```
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]    # rax = address of r
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]      # edx = value of a (deferences r)
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]   # rax = address of p1
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx      # rax = p1, [rax] = *p1, edx = a
```

`int *p2; *p2 = a;` Pointer `*p2` is stored in `rbp-24`. As with `p1`, `p2` is assigned a value without pointing first to any valid address:

```
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]  # edx = value a
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]  # rax = address of p2
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx     # rax = p2, [rax] = *p2, edx = a
```

Answer (score -2):

[Link To alias Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719404/how-to-define-an-alias-to-a-pointer-to-an-integer)

```
int a = 1;
int &r = a; // alias pointers reference above
cout << &a << " " << &r << endl; // 0x61ff10 0x61ff10 (Both address are same)


// It will also not work because you are not initializing p1
int *p1;
*p1 = r;
cout << p1 << endl; // Segmentation Fault

// Same but working code
int *p1 = &r;
cout << p1 << endl; // 0x61ff60


// cannot work (Because you have not initialized p2)
int *p2;
*p2 = a;

// Initialize p2 with a directly
int *p2 = &a; 
cout << p2 << endl; // This time same address as of a
// or
int *p2 = new int;
*p2 = a;
cout << p2 << endl; // This time different address but same value of a
```

Comment: Not true, `ref` is a reference to `a`, you can't assign it to a pointer directly.

Comment: "`int* ptr = ref; // This will work`" no it won't compile. Try it yourself in a compiler.

Comment: Yep. You all were right. I wasn't initializing that ptr...

Comment: "`// Segmentation Fault`" not really. Read all the comments on the question and the other answers. It's UB. Segmentation fault is just one of the possible behaviors. As the OP experienced it can also appear to work, no segfault.